# Components not rendered when created dynamically with array.map in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, babeljs, webpack-dev-server

I am learning react. I wanted to create 8 identical elements in a container.

The following is my code

```
class Card extends React.Component{
    render(){
        return(
          <div className="card">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. </p>
          </div>
        )
    }
}
```

The container component is given below.

```
class Cardholder extends React.Component{
    render(){
        const cards = new Array(9).map((e,i)=> <Card key={i}/>);
        return(
            <div>
                {cards}
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Cardholder;
```

Both components are in same file. The components are not rendered. There are no errors. The message shown in browser console is the following.

> [Log] [HMR] Waiting for update signal from WDS...
>
> [Info] [WDS] Hot Module Replacement enabled.

When I give the array as

```
new Array(9).fill(<Card/>)
```

it works. But there is "key" error as there is no key value specified for the elements.

Comment: Cards will still be an array. Have you tried joining the stings: `new Array(9).map(...).join('')`? Or will React do this automatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
new Array(9) //produce 9 undefined
```

callback is invoked only for indexes of the array which have assigned values

```
new Array(9).fill(null).map((e,i)=> <Card key={i}/>);
```

Answer (score 1):

For empty array, it is returning an empty array and not indexes. I think this is the issue.

```
arr.map((e,i) => i)
```

So you should try something like

```
var arr = new Array(9).fill(0)
```

And then it would work.

Since for empty array map is also returning empty array nothing is being rendered.